# Office 2016 Pro Plus x64 bit - Save as issue

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

Office 2016 Pro Plus x64 bit version no. 16.0.4266.1001

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. From word, powerpoint, excel or any office app, click file > save as
2. Click any recently saved location (under current folder / today /
   this week), and it will open “save as dialog box” with
   C:\users\username\documents

**Example:** when I choose c:\users\username\documents\work under recent saved location, it opens c:\users\username\documents

**Troubleshooting done:**

1. Install office updates
2. Repair office 2016
3. Restart laptop
4. Tried changing default save location, but office apps still opens
   "save as dialog box” with C:\users\username\documents whenever you click on
   any recent saved locations

Comment: When you say you tried changing the default save location, did you try this: Click the File tab, and then click Options.
Click Save.
In the first section, type the path in the Default local file location box.

Comment: This is happening with the Desktop version of the Office apps...not the UWP versions?